# MediaWiki: multiple recipients when user changes email

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm running a wiki based on mediawiki 1.21.11. Because I can't prevent users to change their e-mail address, I want to get informed (e.g. by mail) about this change.

My question: is there any possibility to send e. g. a **copy of the notification mail** or another notification including the old or new e-mail address to a specified recipient when users change their e-mail address?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent users from changing their email address with an [auth plugin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/AuthPlugin), although it seems like a horrible thing to do. You can use some hook to send you notifications - [`PrefsEmailAudit`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/PrefsEmailAudit) or [`UserSetEmail`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/UserSetEmail) if you don't require confirmations, [`ConfirmEmailComplete`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ConfirmEmailComplete) if you do.